# POST HTTP request to login with username and password with Java script and c++

Tags: c++, http, post, authentication

I have been developing an application with `C++` and some parts require connection to http servers, I managed to send *GET* and *HEAD* requests and retrieve the webpage.

Currently, I'm trying to send a *POST* request form to a website that requires login in informations,  It is similar to the *GET* request, however, I don't know how to write it.

let's say:

```
POST /users/login HTTP/1.1
HOST: www.example.com
Content-Length: 50, 
username: ME
password: pass
```

and then receive authentication to retrieve login required pages,

How can I write my *POST* request!?

The website uses a form authentication. I mean there is a box to enter the email address and a password and then hit submit. to my knowledge it is written in *JS*.

Any help or direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try rewriting your request as:

```
POST /users/login HTTP/1.1
HOST: www.example.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 25

username=ME&password=pass
```

I think '25' is the correct length.

As an exercise you could download HTTP tools that allow debugging like WireShark and then log in to a general forum that doesn't have secure log in systems like those typically used with phpbb forums.

Comment: This should work.  Presuming that "username" and "password" are the names of the fields on the form.  A quick glance at the HTML is all that is needed.  Firebug now has an HTTP monitor built into it.  Fiddler (www.fiddler2.com) is another great tool for monitor HTTP messages. @Moe - once you "login", you'll likely need to keep track of a cookie for subsequent requests. (Otherwise, you wouldn't need to login in the first place!).  Consider "curl" as suggested below on WinInet API built into Windows.

Comment: 25 is correct length provided the usename is ME and password is pass. If these parameters change then the length will change.

Answer (score 0):

The POST is one among the http methods like GET,HEAD etc., 
Few basics regarding the the HTTP itself. It is a text based protocol (You can connect to port 80 of the server using a telnet client like putty and type the whole request by hand).

The first line contains the method (GET,HEAD,POST etc.,) the URL path and the HTTP protocol version you support. I recommend to use HTTP1.0 since you wont send multiple request within the same connection. This is harder to implement.

The next set of lines are called headers each line contains a key(content-type,content-length, host etc.,) and a value separated by a ':'.

Then whatever is sent is the body of the request. The information has to be urlencoded. Read through http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Now coming to your problem if you already know how to perform GET then with that assumption for a POST following steps are required.

1. The request will be "POST  HTTP/1.0"
2. Send atleast these headers

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length:

1. As body send the urlencoded text containing the inputname1=value1&inputname2=valule2
2. Now you should get the information back from the server.

Hope this helps. If you want to know more read through the http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/draft-ietf-http-spec.html

Comment: Thank you ferosekhanj, you noted that the body contains inputname1=value1&inputname2=valule2, how would you know what is inputname1 and inpute name2 , is it eh id= or name= in the html source file,  this is what I have 
 
<ul class='vertical form striped hoverable'> 
<li> 
<label for="user_email">Email address</label> 
<input class="text" id="user_email" name="user[email]" size="30" type="text" /> 
</li> 
<li> 
<label for="user_password">Password</label> 
<input class="text" id="user_password" name="user[password]" size="30" type="password" /> 
</li> 
<li>

Comment: Sorry for replying late. It is the name of your input tag.